# spring batch - how to avoid re-loading(writing) data that was loaded in the previous run

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a basic spring batch app which is trying to load the data from a csv file to mysql. the program does load the file into db during the first run. However when I accidently re-run the job/app again, it had thrown the primary key violation (for the right reasons).

What is the best way to avoid reloading the data that is present on the target system? when the batch job is scheduled, if for any good reason, the source file has not changed since the previous run, I want to see 0 record processed message rather than a primary key violation error. hope it makes sense.

more information:
Thanks. I have probably not understood the answer. Let me explain my requirement in a better way. I have a file contains the data from external data source (say new hire data) with a fixed name of hire.csv. The file should be updated with the delta changes for every run. As there is a possibility of manual error of not removing all loaded rows, some new hires from previous run would also be present on current run. Is there a mechanism available within itemreader or itemprocessor to skip those records that are already present on the target db? I can do "insert into tb where not in (select from tb)" but this run for every row which I dont want to use. Hope it is clear now. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However when I accidently re-run the job/app again, it had thrown the primary key violation (for the right reasons). What is the best way to avoid reloading the data that is present on the target system?

The file you are ingesting should be a (identifying) job parameter. This way, when the first run succeeds, the job instance is complete and cannot be run again. This is by design in Spring Batch for this very use case: preventing accidental job execution twice by error.

**Edit:** Add further options based on comments

- If deleting the file is an option, then you can use a job listener or a final step to delete the file after ingesting it. With this option, you need to add a second identifying paramter (since the file name is always `hire.csv`) to make sure you have a different job instance for each run. This option does not require having a different file name for each run.
- If the file can be renamed to `hire-${timestamp}.csv` and will be unique, then deleting the file after ingesting it and using a single job parameter with the filename is enough

*Side note:* I have seen people using a business key to identify records in the input file and using an item processor to query the database and filter items that have been already ingested. This works for small datasets but performs poorly with large datasets due to the additional query for each item.

Comment: thanks Mahmoud Ben Hassine. Edited my original post with more explanation.

Comment: Is deleting the file after each run an option for you? Does the file has to have the same name instead of a name+timestamp ?

Comment: I think I should go far the delete option. I will continue to explore other options in the meantime so that program would never fail even if the re-creation of the new file contains already loaded rows. Thanks for your inputs.